# Show that $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s} X, n \rightarrow \infty \ \ \nRightarrow X_n \xrightarrow{L^{1}} x, n \rightarrow \infty $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show that with an example that:

$X_n\xrightarrow{a.s} X, n \rightarrow \infty \ \ \nRightarrow X_n \xrightarrow{L^{1}} x, n \rightarrow \infty $
where a.s. means the almost surely convergence.

I tried to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to find such an example but I'm still struggling. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Search for $X_n = a_n1_{A_n}$ with $a_n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaled characteristic function $X_n:=n\chi_{\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]}$ should suffice: for fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus0$ eventually $X_n(x)=0$, so $X_n$ limits to $0$ a.s., but $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n\rvert]=1$ always.

---

Just for fun, here's an example for the other direction ($L^1$ [or even $L^p$] does not imply a.s.). Let $H_n:=\sum^n\frac{1}{m}$ be the $n$th Harmonic number and let $X_n:=\chi_{(H_{n-1},H_n)\pmod{1}}$ where we let the intervals in the support "wrap around." Then the support size is $\frac{1}{n}$ so we can easily prove that $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_n\rvert^p]=\frac{1}{n}$ limiting to 0, but we can see that for all $x\in(0,1)$ there are infinitely many $m,n$ with $X_n(x)=1$ and $X_m(x)=0$.